# How to pass functional component as a value for QRCode in React Native

Tags: react-native, qr-code

I am trying to create QR code for a Portfolio card which is nothing but a functional component which should be displayed when QR code will be scanned. But I can see QRCode only accepts String values so how should I achieve this?

```
export default function PortfolioCard() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.heading}>My Portfolio</Text>
      <View style={styles.card}>
         // rest of the code
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

// Below is what I want to do but that's giving error

```
function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
      <View>
         <QRCode
              value={<PortfolioCard />}
         />
      </View>
  );
}
```

[image: card which should be displayed on QR code scan]

Comment: The value is what the QR code represents, usually a link, so it should be a string. What exactly do you want to happen? User opens your app, scans QR code, then what?

Comment: and then the PortfolioCard should be displayed to the user. The image of sample PortfolioCard I have added in description.

Comment: that's not how you would do that, you would need to replace the QR component with the card component.  Try looking up conditional rendering in React

Comment: Any sample or any direction if you give me then it would be great